# Altium Track vs Trace?

Tags: pcb-design, altium

In Altium Designer I see in *PCB Inspector* (*Workspace Panel*) both *Track* and *Trace* objects.

In my opinion *Track* is standard Altium object (conductive path between pads), then what is *Trace*, and what's the difference?

Comment: FWIW, a recent conversation with a professional PCB designer and English speaker taught me that track and traces are interchangeable in the PCB context. Not sure about Altium though.

Comment: Your question would be meaningful if you could link or post a photo of Trace object